# Notification handling with Windows Forms

Tags: c#, event-handling, opc

I have the following code which handles the change notification from the server:

```
//this is the notification control to process the change value event.
    public  void OnNotification(MonitoredItem monitoredItem, MonitoredItemNotificationEventArgs e,
        MonitorHandler mh)
    {
        //check which thread called OnNotification 

        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate () { OnNotification(monitoredItem, e, mh); });
               
        }
        else
        {
            mh.monitoredItem = monitoredItem;
            foreach (var value in monitoredItem.DequeueValues())
            {
                mh.SetValue(value);
                mh.SetQuality(value);
                mh.SetTimeStamp(value);

                if (loggingOn)
                {
                    //add to log
                   log.AddRecord(monitoredItem, value);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Windows forms do update, however program somehow misses about half of notifications. Doesn't matter for the GUI, but it is important for the log.

If I call logging function synchronously:

```
public void OnNotification(MonitoredItem monitoredItem, MonitoredItemNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var value in monitoredItem.DequeueValues())
        {
            if (loggingOn)
            {
                //add to log
                log.AddRecord(monitoredItem, value);
            }
        }

    }
```

logging works perfectly, but of course the windows forms will throw the exception about cross-thread operation not valid.

Logger function just adds time-value pairs to xml document:

```
public void AddRecord(MonitoredItem item, DataValue value)
    {
        var str = item.DisplayName.Replace("\"", "");
        //find the right element
        var searchStr = "log/Tag[@Name='" + str + "']";
        var tagNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(searchStr);
        if (tagNode !=null)
        {
           var dpAdd = dpNode.CloneNode(true);
            //time node
           dpAdd.FirstChild.InnerText = value.ServerTimestamp.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff");
            //value node
           dpAdd.LastChild.InnerText = value.WrappedValue.ToString();

           tagNode.AppendChild(dpAdd);
        }
     }
```

I am confused by this behavior because even if notifications come on different threads, they should all end up calling the AddRecord function? Any help would be appreciated. As a quick fix, how can I call logger synchronously from the same event handler as forms update?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe the `monitoredItem` changed in the next event.

Try to `DequeueValues` first, then pass into the `BeginInvoke` part.

And just use `BeginInvoke`  to update UI.

If your log method does not update UI.  Call it synchronously.

Comment: yes thanks, I tried doing that but if I do anything before the beginInvoke part, it throws the  cross-thread exception. What I did is I subscribed both event handlers to the same event and it is working correctly right now. Ugly solution, and behavior is still not fully understood.